# python regular expression case change

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for a more robust way to convert the string below. I want to find the first 3 letters of the 3 words and change the case. The words could be anything, right now I'm just using string replace for each lower case letter.

```
s1 = 'hello.crazy.world.txt'

s1 = s1.replace('h','H')
```

Comment: Are all words separated by a dot? Don't use `str` as a variable. You are shadowing the built-in `str` and will surely have issues using the actual `str` object.

Comment: `split('.')` and `title()` are good methods to use

Comment: Yes, all separated by a dot. Good point about the var name, I changed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) capitalizes groups of consecutive letters - you'll just have to exclude the extension.

One way to do that:

```
In [5]: name, ext = s.rsplit('.', 1)

In [6]: '{}.{}'.format(name.title(), ext)
Out[6]: 'Hello.Crazy.World.txt'
```

Comment: `rsplit` seems like a nice solution - didn't know about that

Comment: I like this solution but what exactly is '{}.{}' doing?

Comment: @iheartcpp: concatenates `name.title()`, `'.'`, and `ext` https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.capitalize`

```
s1 = 'hello.crazy.world.txt'
out = '.'.join([i.capitalize() for i in s1.split('.')])
```

This capitalizes all the first letters, producing `'Hello.Crazy.World.Txt'`.

If you would like to do it for the first three words only, you can use a slice, and then append the extension.

```
s1 = 'hello.crazy.world.txt'
split = s1.split('.')
extension = split[-1]
capitalized = [i.capitalize() for i in split[:-1]]
capitalized.append(extension)
out = '.'.join(capitalized)
```

This produces `'Hello.Crazy.World.txt'`.

The advantages of using capitalize over title is title capitalizes every word following a period, if you have an item you would not like to capitalize, you can omit the item (such as the last item in this case).

A more compact way would be using list comprehension to capitalize each item, with the exception of the last item, merge the lists and join the result string in a single step.:

```
s1 = 'hello.crazy.world.txt'
split = s1.split('.')
out = '.'.join([i.capitalize() for i in split[:-1]] + [split[-1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is using .title():

```
>>> "hello.crazy.world.txt".title()
"Hello.Crazy.World.Txt"
```

Since you don't want to capitalize the last part, you'd do:

```
parts = "hello.crazy.world.txt".split(".")
result = '.'.join(parts[:-1]).title() + "." + parts[-1]
```

Comment: I know, edited the answer, you were faster than I was typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is ambiguous on this, I think you want something like this:

```
import os
st_filename = 'hello.crazy.world.txt'
st_base, st_ext = os.path.splitext(st_filename)
st_base = st_base.title()
st_filename = ''.join(st_base, st_ext)
# I am unsure if the splitext will work across platforms to be rejoined with join, but it seems to work on linux and Mac OS X
```